# Rails not throwing routing error when invalid url is entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

In my rails 2.3.X application there is User resource which is nested under many other resources and is not exposed directly.

```
 map.resources :resource1 do |r|
   r.resources :users
 end
 map.resources :resource2 do |r|
   r.resources :users
 end
 # map.resources :users is not mentioned any where.
```

When I hit "/user" or "/users-any-invalid-url" it shows routing error but when I hit "/users" it takes me to index action of users_controller which is not desired. I want to get the same routing error.

How to get that? Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a rails 2 app, there is a default route found at the bottom of `route.rb`

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

So as long as your have a users controller, it will go to that controller.  The solution is to simply remove those 2 lines.  Removing those 2 lines also protect you from various unwanted requests.